# Variable declarations conventions/rules in Java MVC pattern?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, design-patterns, jsp, servlets

I am a novice in Java World. How to avoid confusion over variable declaration in MVC pattern over same variable?

For Example,

In Servlet (Controller):

```
String firstName     = request.getParameter("firstname");
String lastName      = request.getParameter("lastname");
```

In Bean (Model):

```
private String firstname;
private String lastname;

public Person(String FirstName, String LastName) {
    setFirstName(FirstName);
    setLastName(LastName);
}

//Getter and Setter Methods
public String getFirstName() {
  return firstname;
}
public void setFirstName(String FirstName) {
  this.firstname = FirstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
  return lastname;
}
public void setLastName(String LastName) {
  this.lastname = LastName;
}
```

In DAO (Data Access Layer):

```
public void savePerson(String firstName, String lastName) {
    // Method statements
}
```

And in JSP (View):

```
${person.firstname} ${person.lastname}
```

My Questions/Confusion?

1. What is the proper way of declaring same variable in different
    modules(controller,models,views,dao)? And how should I avoid confusion?
2. Is there any conventions I have to follow while declaring variables in different
    modules?
3. Should variables in Servlets and DAO be same? Should variables in Models/Bean 
    be different from Servlet and DAO?

Comment: At least, be consistent. Don't mix `firstname`, `firstName` and `FirstName`. This makes no sense. Just use `firstName` everywhere. Do yourself and your future Java code maintainers a favour.

Comment: Previously, I thought for each module there should be separate variable declarations. But now, I got the point. Declaring it in Model/Bean and accessing it from  anywhere. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your servlet these would be method variables. That's pretty fine.

In your Model this works as a Model's properties. That's pretty fine, too.

In view you are actually referring to Model's properties, and not declaring any variable, whatsoever.

In DAO, you are actually, persisting your Model.

So, In Servlet/Controller this will be something more like this,

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setFirstName(request.getParameter("firstname"));
p.setLastName(request.getParameter("lastname"));
```

And in your DAO, it would be more like this,

```
public void savePerson(Person person) {
    // Method statements
}
```

Hence, declaration only happens in `Model`. I hope it clears your confusion.

Comment: Okay. I got the concept you are saying. That's much more simple than I used to do before. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think the variable names you have used are fine. You can name your classes based on the type of the module. So you could name your classes using names like MyApplicationController, EmployeeModel, EmployeeDAO, etc.